# ¿Cómo hago que el Else de mi función en Python, si le dan una opción inválida, no vuelva a reiniciar el bucle while?

Tags: python

Me pasa que si la opción llega al `else` de la funcion `volver_a_ejecutar`, en vez de hacer una salida del bucle vuelve al principio.
¿Como puedo hacer que vuelva a preguntar si quiere seguir usando la calculadora o no?

Dejo el código para que lo lean

```
#Definimos las funciones que usara la calculadora

def sumar(*args):
    return a + b

def restar(*args):
    return a - b

def dividir(a, b):
    return a / b

def multiplicar(a, b):
    return a * b 

####################################################

#creacion del bucle de la calculadora
ejecutar = True
while ejecutar:
    try:
        a = int(input("Ingrese el numero a calcular: ")) #Le pedimos al usuario el primer numero
        b = int(input("Ingresa el segundo numero: ")) #Le pedimos al usuario el segundo numero
        cuenta = input(""" Ingresa que calculo quieres hacer con estos numeros:
                        
        1 - Sumar
        2 - Restar 
        3 - Dividir
        4 - Multiplicar\n
        """) #Le pedimos al usuario que ingrese la opcion de la operacion que quiere realizar
          
        if cuenta == "1":
            print("La suma de ",a," + ",b," da el resultado de ",sumar(a, b))
        
        elif cuenta == "2":
            print("La resta de ",a," - ",b," da el resultado de ",restar(a, b))
                            
        elif cuenta == "3":
            print("La division de ",a," / ",b," da el resultado de ",dividir(a, b))
                            
        elif cuenta == "4":
            print("La multiplicacion de ",a," * ",b," da el resultado de ",multiplicar(a, b))
                        
        else:
            print("Esa no es una opcion valida")
        
        #crea una salida del bucle al finalizar la operacion
        
        volver_a_ejecutar = input("Quieres volver a ejecutar la calculadora? [s/n]")
        
        if volver_a_ejecutar == "n":
            break
        elif volver_a_ejecutar == "s":
            pass
        else:
            print("Por favor ingresa una opcion valida")
            
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("No se puede dividir por cero, intenta con otro numero.")
                        
    except:
        print("Error")
```

Comment: pon un `break` y listo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que te falta es añadir otro while dado que quieres controlar todas las opciones de salida. Yo lo primero crearía una lista con las opciones

```
opciones = ['s', 'n']
```

Ahora es donde viene el otro bloque añadiendo el nuevo `while`

```
        # crea una salida del bucle al finalizar la operacion
        volver_a_ejecutar = ''
        while volver_a_ejecutar not in opciones:

            volver_a_ejecutar = input ( "Quieres volver a ejecutar la calculadora? [s/n]" ).lower()

            if volver_a_ejecutar == "n":
                ejecutar = False
            elif volver_a_ejecutar == "s":
                pass
            else:
                print ( "Por favor ingresa una opcion valida" )
```

inicias la variable a algo que no corresponda con 's' o 'n' y repites mientras no corresponda.

Comment: Buenisimo, me funciono perfecto. Y entendi la explicacion, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un break o setear la variable `ejecutar` en false:

Agregando un break:

```py
else:
  print("Esa no es una opcion valida")
  break      
  #crea una salida del bucle al finalizar la operacion
```

Cambiando la variable de control del bucle

```py
else:
  print("Esa no es una opcion valida")
  ejecutar = False      
  #crea una salida del bucle al finalizar la operacion
```

Comment: claro,pero eso seria en el primer else, yo quiero que con la pregunta de la funcion `volver_a_ejecutar` dando el input de "s" siga a hacer una operacion y con el "n" se cierre la aplicacion, pero si le entra una opcion que no sean ninguna de esas dos y va al `else` de la funcion, vuelve al while del principio. Mi idea es que repregunte si quiere o no seguir. Perdon si me explico medio mal porque recien arranco a programar medio autodidacta y soy un desastre jaja

Comment: En ese caso la respuesta de Tomy es la indicada para tu pregunta

Comment: Yo me explique mal en la pregunta, despues lo edite para que se entienda mejor.  De igual manera muchas gracias!